# Polymorphic callbacks in data constructor

Tags: haskell

I'm just starting to learn haskell. I have custom class

```
class MyClass a where
  doSomething :: a -> ()
```

Can I write a data with polymorphic callback in constructor?

```
data MyData = MyConstructor {
  callback :: (MyClass m) => m -> () -- error
}
```

I want to make constraint for function argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, Yes you can by using `Rank2Types` or `RankNTypes` pragma.

As your data type is existentially quantified. It is actually

```
data MyData = MyConstructor (forall m. MyClass m => m -> ())
```

for which you require higher rank extension.